# How to resolve a Q deferred object multiple times, i.e. make resolve by steps?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, q

I have a flow of functions one of which (the `first` function) is asynchronous and returns a promise. This function calls other async functions (`nestedAssyncFunction_*`). The second function must be called, when the first one and all of its nested functions return. So I need to resolve the deferred object in several places (in the example in three nested functions).

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
first().then(second);

function first() {
    nestedAssyncFunction_1();
    nestedAssyncFunction_2();
    nestedAssyncFunction_3();
    return deferred.promise;
}
function second() {
    // some actions
}
```

So my main question is: **how to resolve a deferred in several steps**?

What I found up to that moment is that I can call `notify` method from several places and and inside its handler resolve the main deferred object. Like this:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
deferred.progressCounter = 0;

first().then(second, undefined, notifyHandler);

function notifyHandler() {
    deferred.progressCounter++;
    if (deferred.progressCounter === 3) {
        deferred.resolve();
    }
}
function nestedAssyncFunction_1() {
    // some actions
    deferred.notify();
}
```

But then my question is: **what is the best way to add custom properties to a deferred object**?
Cause it seems to be frowned to do it, like in the example above.

My appreciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not what you want at all.

What you want:

```
Q.all([
   nestedAssyncFunction_1(),
   nestedAssyncFunction_2(),
   nestedAssyncFunction_3()
]).then(function(){
    //All done
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
function first() {
    //All you nested functions have to return a promise
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(nestedAssyncFunction_1());
    promises.push(nestedAssyncFunction_2());
    promises.push(nestedAssyncFunction_3());

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    Q.all(promises).then(function(){
         //do some tasks after all promises are resolve.

         deferred.resolve(); //resolve deferred objects when all promises are resolved.
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function second() {
    // some actions
}
```

Or this solution (depend what on your needs, you could choose this or the first solution):

```
function first() {
        //All you nested functions have to return a promise
        var promises = [];
        promises.push(nestedAssyncFunction_1());
        promises.push(nestedAssyncFunction_2());
        promises.push(nestedAssyncFunction_3());

        var deferred = Q.defer();
        promises.push(deferred.promise);//push the promise of current function

        //do something asynch with the current function and call deferred.resolve()

        return Q.all(promises);//Combine all promises into one
    }

    function second() {
        // some actions
    }
```

Chain the functions like this:

```
first().then(second);
```